# Можно ли этот эффект получить на css?

Tags: javascript, css

Можно ли не применяя `clip-path css` получить такой же эффект как в этом `svg` ?

```html
<svg 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewbox='0 0 640 480'
     preserveAspectRatio="none" >
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect fill="#555552" width="640px" height="480px" />
      <g style="fill:white;">
        <rect x="20px"  y="20px" width="100px" height="100px" />
        <rect x="140px" y="20px" width="100px" height="100px" />
        <rect x="260px" y="20px" width="100px" height="100px" />

        <rect x="20px"  y="140px" width="100px" height="100px" />
        <rect x="140px" y="140px" width="100px" height="100px" />
        <rect x="260px" y="140px" width="100px" height="100px" />

        <rect x="20px"  y="260px" width="100px" height="100px" />
        <rect x="140px" y="260px" width="100px" height="100px" />
        <rect x="260px" y="260px" width="100px" height="100px" />
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
 <g>
  <rect fill="#000" width="640px" height="480px" />
  <image xlink:href="//i.stack.imgur.com/7fqK5.jpg"
         width="640px"
         height="480px"
        style="mask:url(#mask);"/>
  </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Ну тоже маской, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле svg-mask ?

Comment: Или mix-blend-mode.

Comment: @Qwertiy покажи на blend-mode

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

Comment: @Qwertiy  там же опять svg

Comment: Не только svg. И чем не угодил svg?

Comment: @Qwertiy на svg я сам умею,Alexandr_TT меня научил

Answer (score 7, accepted):

opacity + linear-gradient:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fqK5.jpg) no-repeat;
  margin:0;
}

div {
  height: 200vh;
  --lines:  
      #000   24px, #0000  26px, 
      #0000  99px, #000  101px, 
      #000  124px, #0000 126px, 
      #0000 199px, #000  201px,
      #000  224px, #0000 226px, 
      #0000 299px, #000  301px;
  background: linear-gradient(          var(--lines)), 
              linear-gradient(to right, var(--lines));
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<div>
```

Comment: прошлая фотка круче была!

Comment: @MaximLensky там она рандомная была, решил вставить из вопроса

Comment: я назначу конкурс - отмечу решением уже в командировке

Comment: @MaximLensky хоть не в Китай?

Comment: упаси Господь ..чур меня.. в нашу Казашу

Answer (score 7):

Резиновая таблица с полупрозрачными бордерами) `border-collapse: collapse` на месте стыков создавал темные квадратики, поэтому вместо него использован `border-spacing: 0;`

Толщина бордеров и количество клеток настраивается через дата-атрибуты.

```js
let wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.js-table-grid-wrap');

wrappers.forEach(function(wrap) {
  wrap.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', createTableGrid(wrap));

  /***/

  function createTableGrid(wrap) {
    let borderWidth = +wrap.dataset.halfStroke;
    let cells = +wrap.dataset.cells || 5;
    let rows = +wrap.dataset.rows || 5;
    
    let style = `style="border-width: ${borderWidth}px;"`;
    
    return (
      `<table ${style}>` +
        ("<tr>" + 
          `<td ${style}></td>`.repeat(cells) + 
        "</tr>").repeat(rows) +
      `</table>`
    );
  }
});
```

```css
.js-table-grid-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden; /* Если сильно сожмут и пиксельные бордеры окажутся толще дырок */
  
  width: 50%;

  --border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.js-table-grid-wrap table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: var(--border-color);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.js-table-grid-wrap td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: var(--border-color);
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.js-table-grid-wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-table-grid-wrap" data-cells="5" data-rows="5" data-half-stroke="12"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fqK5.jpg"></div>
```

P.s. на самом деле тоже сделал бы на repeating-linear-gradient, но он уже предлагался)

Comment: О, табличка. Оригинально ^_^

Answer (score 5):

Решение на чистом CSS без применения `clip-path`
Плюс бонусом возможность передвигать элементы

```js
$(".mask__1,.mask__2,.mask__3,.mask__4,.mask__5,.mask__6,.mask__7,.mask__8,.mask__9").draggable({containment: "parent"});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body,html {width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 380px;}
.mask__1,.mask__2,.mask__3,.mask__4,.mask__5,.mask__6,.mask__7,.mask__8,.mask__9 {position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; height: 100px;}.mask__1 {top: 20px; left: 20px;}.mask__2 {top: 20px; left: 140px;}.mask__3 {top: 20px; left: 260px;}.mask__4 {top: 140px; left: 20px;}.mask__5 {top: 140px; left: 140px;}.mask__6 {top: 140px; left: 260px;}.mask__7 {top: 260px; left: 20px;}.mask__8 {top: 260px; left: 140px;}.mask__9 {top: 260px; left: 260px;}
.mask__1:before,.mask__2:before,.mask__3:before,.mask__4:before,.mask__5:before,.mask__6:before,.mask__7:before,.mask__8:before,.mask__9:before {content: ""; display: block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 380px; z-index: 1; filter: none; cursor: move; background-image: url(https://s1.1zoom.me/b5050/913/400993-sepik_1920x1200.jpg); background-attachment: fixed !Important; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%;}
.masked {position: absolute; top: 0;  left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 380px; background-image: url(https://s1.1zoom.me/b5050/913/400993-sepik_1920x1200.jpg); background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; filter: brightness(20%);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="mask__1"></div><div class="mask__2"></div><div class="mask__3"></div><div class="mask__4"></div><div class="mask__5"></div><div class="mask__6"></div><div class="mask__7"></div><div class="mask__8"></div><div class="mask__9"></div>
<div class="masked"></div>
```

Comment: Скроллится сомнительно. И куча div'ов с одинаковыми id. А так, идея интересная :)

Comment: Можно было основному фону тоже `background-attachment: fixed` задать. А зачем тебе id, я в принципе не понимаю - вроде ты их особо и не используешь, можно было просто два класса сделать. А вместо `unmask` можно вообще использовать псевдоэлемент.

Answer (score 3):

Что-то вроде такого:

```css
.pomidori {
  background-image: 
    url('https://i.artfile.ru/1600x1200_343377_[www.ArtFile.ru].jpg'),
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,
      rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0px, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 10px,
      white 10px, white 40px
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg,
      rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0px, rgba(0,0,0,.5) 10px,
      white 10px, white 40px
    );
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position:0 0, 5px 5px;
  background-blend-mode: multiply; 
  
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pomidori">
</div>
```

Comment: вроде бы ни чё так + поставил

Answer (score 3):

Подход скорее на css трюк похож, но, думаю, из этого можно кое-что и вытянуть:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: url("https://www.thewowstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/natural-landscape.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
body:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 2rem;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  background-image: url("https://www.thewowstyle.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/natural-landscape.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: красиво получилось + от меня